# USB Type-C port -> DP on monitor ThinkVision P27q-20 not working with HP ProBook 450 G7 on Ubuntu 20.4.1

Tags: 20.04, hp, displayport, usb-c

I have the following configuration.

- Monitor Lenovo ThinkVision P27q-20
- Laptop HP ProBook 450 G7 with Intel UHD graphics.
- Ubuntu 20.04.1, kernel 5.4.0-48-generic

I connected USB Type-C port of the laptop by adapter cable with the Display Port of monitor. The monitor stays blank and the notebook mouse and display freeze after 5-10 seconds. When I unplug the cable, the laptop unfreezes after a while. The problem is repeatable.

I checked the following when the cable is plugged in:

```
    lsusb -t 
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
 ** |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

The line Bus 01.Port1.Port 6 is the new device. lsusb identifies it as

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2109:0103 VIA Labs, Inc. USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
```

Inspecting dmesg does not give more information neither

```
[ 6872.474669] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 6872.638522] usb 1-6: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 6872.655981] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0103, bcdDevice=10.04
[ 6872.655989] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6872.655994] usb 1-6: Product: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             
[ 6872.655998] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: VIA Technologies Inc.         
[ 6872.656001] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[ 6884.925603] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

/var/log/syslog has an additional read error -71. (line 2)

```
Oct 11 19:25:33 helap kernel: [ 7417.093277] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Oct 11 19:25:33 helap kernel: [ 7417.429281] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.703006] usb 1-6: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.720708] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0103, bcdDevice=10.04
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.720712] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.720715] usb 1-6: Product: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.720718] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: VIA Technologies Inc.         
Oct 11 19:25:34 helap kernel: [ 7417.720719] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
Oct 11 19:25:42 helap kernel: [ 7426.316434] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

lsmod shows typec modules

```
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
```

I also checked the cable with my ThinkPad notebook (running Windows 10), and it worked fine. (Windows also identifies the VIA USB 2.0 BILLBOARD usb device).

Switching to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS did not help either.

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: resolved by bios update